# Devops Pipeline - Catch sql query result in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I have a devops pipeline (running on an agent in a local server) with a custom task that executes an SQL query using sqlcmd.
I want to catch the result of this query to use in another step.
Any idea about how to do ?
[image]

Comment: It all depends on what your other step is. There are so many options, even just in Windows stack. I would start with SQL PowerShell cmdlets. If the output is a large data set, then you can try SSIS or BCP.

Comment: You could set a variable so another task can consume the data. You could write the data to a specific file path so a next task can use that file in the same job. You can save it to a file and then register as a pipeline atrefact, that way subsequent jobs and other pipelines can download the result with the Download Pipeline Artefact task. Can you explain a bit more what your intended workflow would look like and what kind of data to pass along?

Comment: Should i use an output variable for this task if i want to "You could set a variable so another task can consume the data" ? The artifact that triggers this deployment pipeline contains N components (Several WS, SQL scripts....). All components should not be deployed. We have a table in an sql server db to retreive the components to be deployed (updated each weekly release). I Want to catch the name of the components that should not be deployed using an sql script (sql step in the screenshot), in order to use it in a very next "delete from artifact" step.. and deploy the remaining components.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

1. gen sql script file task
2. run sql script task and set response as pipeline variables

There are 2 scoped variables, it's more easy to use global scoped variable, the value of variable only support string as far as I know.
"##vso[task.setvariable variable={variableName};]{variableValue}"

```
Import-Module SqlServer
$result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile $SqlScript -ServerInstance $DBServer -Username $DBUser -Password $DBPassword -Database $DBName -OutputSqlErrors $true -verbose
foreach($row in $result) {
    Write-Host ($row | Format-Table | Out-String)
}
```

3. consume sql response data task